# \prg_do_nothing: vs \scan_stop:

Tags: latex3

There are two no operation functions in LaTeX3 called `\prg_do_nothing:` and `\scan_stop:`. What is the difference between them? Which one is preferable?

Comment: Or you can learn from how they are defined: `\cs_new:Npn \prg_do_nothing: { }` and `\tex_let:D \scan_stop: \tex_relax:D` in which `\tex_relax:D` is let to primitive `\relax` globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do different things. The functions `\prg_do_nothing:` is expandable, and is documented as expanding to nothing at all. This means that for example

```latex
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \prg_do_nothing: }
\tl_if_empty:NTF \l_tmpa_tl ...
```

will take the `true` branch.

On the other hand, `\scan_stop:` is not expandable, so the same setup

```latex
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \scan_stop: }
\tl_if_empty:NTF \l_tmpa_tl ...
```

takes the `false` branch. The `\scan_stop:` function also acts as a terminator for various low-level TeX constructs, which `\prg_do_nothing:` does not.

Which you want depends on your use case. If you are working by expansion and need a marker that will 'disappear', `\prg_do_nothing:` is the right choice. If you need a marker that will *typeset* nothing but that will surive `x`/`e`-type expansion, you want `\scan_stop:`.